# Oracle 11g создание индексов

Tags: база-данных, oracle

```
create index f_ind_STANDT on STANDT(STANDGEOM)
indextype is mdsys.spatial_index
parameters('sdo_level=4, sdo_numtiles=4');
```

Пытаясь создать подобным способом индекс, получаю следующую ошибку

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
create index f_ind_WAREHOUSET on WAREHOUSET(WAREHOUSEGEOM)
indextype is mdsys.spatial_index
parameters('sdo_level=3')
Error report -
ORA-29855: возникла ошибка при выполнении программы ODCIINDEXCREATE
ORA-13249: internal error in Spatial index: [mdidxrbd]
ORA-13249: Error in Spatial index: index build failed
ORA-13206: внутренняя ошибка [Tessellate] при создании пространственного индекса
ORA-13249: Error in spatial index: [mdpridxtessellate]
ORA-13200: внутренняя ошибка [ROWID:AAAVNFAABAAAXMJAAB] в пространственном индексе.
ORA-13019: координаты вне диапазона
ORA-06512: на  "MDSYS.SDO_INDEX_METHOD_10I", line 10
29855. 00000 -  "error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine"
*Cause:    Failed to successfully execute the ODCIIndexCreate routine.
*Action:   Check to see if the routine has been coded correctly.
```

Создание таблицы:

```
create table StandT(
StandId number constraint StandId primary key,
StandGeom mdsys.sdo_geometry,
StandName varchar2(20)
);
```

Добавление данных:

```
insert into STANDT(STANDID, STANDGEOM, STANDNAME)
values(4, mdsys.sdo_geometry(2003, null, null,
mdsys.sdo_elem_info_array(1,3,3),
mdsys.sdo_ordinate_array(5,9, 13,10)),
'OTHER');
```

Но, несмотря на ошибку, иденкс таки появляется после запроса

```
SELECT INDEX_NAME FROM ALL_INDEXES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'STANDT';
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Несмотря на то, что в списке он появился, выполнить запрос я не могу.
Запрос:

```
select count (st.STANDID) as "stand view"
from STANDT st
where mdsys.sdo_filter(st.STANDGEOM,
mdsts.sdo_geometry(2003,null,null,
mdsys.sdo_elem_info_array(1,3,3),
mdsys.sdo_ordinate_array(1,1,10,10)),
'querytype=window') = 'TRUE';
```

Ошибка:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
select count (st.STANDID) as "stand view"
from STANDT st
where mdsys.sdo_filter(st.STANDGEOM,
mdsts.sdo_geometry(2003,null,null,
mdsys.sdo_elem_info_array(1,3,3),
mdsys.sdo_ordinate_array(1,1,10,10)),
'querytype=window') = 'TRUE'
Error report -
ORA-13226: интерфейс на поддерживается без пространственного индекса
ORA-06512: на  "MDSYS.MD", line 1723
ORA-06512: на  "MDSYS.MDERR", line 8
ORA-06512: на  "MDSYS.SDO_3GL", line 1224
```